# Enable the submit button after adding 2 number and comparing the number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to enable the submit button , there are 3 fields in a form value of 1st field-box is fixed and the addition of 2nd field-box and 3rd field-box is stored in 4th field box. So what i need is it should compare with the 1st number and th3 4th number (addition of 2nd and 3rd) and if the condition satisfied then it should enable the submit button or else button should be disable. I have done some work around and not able to figure it out what i am missing. Please help me regarding the same.

I have added the [JSfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/ritesh2587/nzu7v1Lf/26/) on which I am working:

```js
let $form = $('form');
let $first1 = $('#first1');
let $total1 = $('#total1');
let $total2 = $('#total2');
let $answer = $('#answer');
let $submitButton = $(':submit');

$form.on('submit', function(event) {
  let val1 = Number($first1.val());
  let val2 = Number($answer.val());
  if (val1 < val2) { // If condition is NOT met.
    event.preventDefault(); // Default submit from happening.
    return false; // Stop function.
  }
});

$form.on('input', function(event) {
  let val1 = Number($first1.val());
  let val2 = Number($answer.val());
  console.log(val1, val2)
  let isDisabled = val1 < val2; // Will return true or false.
  $submitButton.prop('disabled', isDisabled);
});

$form.on('input', function(event) {
  let val1 = Number($total1.val());
  let val2 = Number($total2.val());
  console.log(val1, val2)
  let number = parseInt($('#total1').val()) + parseInt($('#total2').val());
  $('#answer').val(number);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="order.php">
  <label for="first1">Fixed Number</label>
  <input type="number" id="first1" value="10" />
  <br>
  <label for="total1">First Number</label>
  <input type="number" id="total1" class="change"/>
  <br>
  <label for="total2">Second Number</label>
  <input type="number" id="total2" class="change"/>
  <br>
  Answer = <input type="number" id="answer" name="answer" value=""/>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" disabled title="Not Relevant">
</form>
```

Comment: Be careful with the order of your callbacks, you're comparing then you're adding so you're always comparing an older version. Also no need to have to call backs, just put all the code in one callback (after swapping the order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your function more by combining the two `input` event listeners and put them in one. And the `submit` event listener is not needed either.

`val1` and `val2` are already numbers cause of the `Number()` constructor wrapping the `$total1.val()` function. It does the same thing as `parseInt`.

Add `val1` to `val2` and store that result in a new variable called `total`.
Then check if the `total` is lower or higher than the `firstVal` (fixed value) and disable or enable the submit button.

Add a `readonly` attribute to inputs that you don't want modified by the user.

```js
let $form = $('form');
let $first1 = $('#first1');
let $total1 = $('#total1');
let $total2 = $('#total2');
let $answer = $('#answer');
let $submitButton = $(':submit');

$form.on('input', function(event) { // This function gets called every time you change the value in one of the inputs
  let firstVal = Number($first1.val()); // Get fixed number
  let val1 = Number($total1.val()); // Get 2nd field number
  let val2 = Number($total2.val()); // Get 3rd field number
  let total = val1 + val2; // Add 2nd and 3rd field
  let isDisabled = total < firstVal; // If total is lower than fixed number, then is true, otherwise is false.
  $submitButton.prop('disabled', isDisabled); // Disable based on if isDisabled is true or false
  $answer.val(total); // Show the total
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="order.php">
  <label for="first1">Fixed Number</label>
  <input type="number" id="first1" value="10" readonly/>
  <br>
  <label for="total1">First Number</label>
  <input type="number" id="total1" class="change"/>
  <br>
  <label for="total2">Second Number</label>
  <input type="number" id="total2" class="change"/>
  <br>
  <label for="answer">Answer</label>
  <input type="number" id="answer" name="answer" value="" readonly/>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" disabled title="Not Relevant">
</form>
```